# Estimating the 95th percentile of nitrate data using non-parametric Weibull method, with associated confidence intervals in R

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, quantiles, weibull-distribution

I am currently involved in a project where I have to estimate the 95th percentile of nitrate data from different sample points, using the non-parametric Weibull method, to see if it breaches the required standard. Then I need to record this at 3 different levels of confidence. I have been using the `car`, `MASS` and `fitdistrplus` packages within R, but am not quite sure of the exact code for the different confidence intervals of the 95th percentile.

What I would like to know is **how to find confidence intervals for the 95th percentile based on this dataset.** and **to create a confidence interval for the percentiles of a Weibull distribution**  `R` examples or implementations would be most welcome.

Comment: Two points, this should probably be migrated to SO as it is a programming question.  Second, when asking programming questions it is customary to provide some sort of representative data and your attempted code.  We are happy to help but these forums are not code writing services.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to code something in R. Without a reproducible example or an attempt at code it is not in my view suitable for Stack Overflow. Please review advice about software-specific questions in the Help Center.

Comment: Hi both, i can give you an example from a sample point(data656). The data is as follows: data656 <- c(8.63, 4.584, 4.909, 5.36, 3.113, 1.42, 0.3, 0.797, 2.288, 2.305, 3.211). Once i have inputted this code into R, I apply the following code: fitdistr(data656, densfun="weibull"), qqPlot(data656, distribution="weibull", shape=, scale=) using the parameters found using the previous function. Then the quantile function quantile e.g. 95th (data656, c( .95)). To find confidence values, i use t.test(data656, conf.level = 0.9), but this only bases confidence intervals on the mean, not on the 95thile??

Comment: What i would like to know is how to find confidence intervals on this data-set based on the 9th percentile rather than the mean, which is used in the t-test function, but i do not know how to about this in R. Any ideas most welcome, appreciate the responses. If this isnt the right forum for this topic, i apologise. Thanks

Comment: Please add the new information into your question by clicking the gray "edit" to its lower left (be sure to use our formatting options). I'm not sure how good of an answer you'll get to this on SO, b/c there are 2 components here: how can this be done, & how can that solution be implemented in R? You might re-focus this thread on Q1 & leave it here to be answered, then ask a new question on SO w/ that solution & ask how to implement it in R.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Anthony.  I have incorporated my interpretation of your last comment within the question, hoping it might hold off any additional votes to close or migrate it in the meantime. But could you explain what you mean by the "non-parametric Weibull method"? This could refer to several different procedures; an obvious one is to fit a Weibull distribution to the data--but that's not "non-parametric."

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for your reply. What i mean is non-paramtetric estimations of the data-set i.e. non-parametric esimations of the percentiles (e.g. the 95th). This non-parametric method assumes a Weibull distribution within the data, as we cant assume the data follows a normal distribution, plus this method is relatviely insensitive to outliers. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Anthony: It still makes not much sense: If you assume that your data follows a specific distribution, like the Weibull distribution, then it's not a non-parametric estimation. [Non-parametric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) pretty much means that you *don't* assume any specific distribution at all. Is your question basically to create a confidence interval for the percentiles of a Weibull distribution? Also, please add any additional information you gave in the comments to the question by using the `edit` button.

Comment: Perhaps this means no more than the use of the so-called Weibull plotting position $i / (n + 1)$ for rank $i$ and sample size $n$, but quite how that is used remains obscure: possibly interpolation between sample quantiles.

Comment: The edit here is "and to create a confidence interval for the percentiles of a Weibull distribution".